# Dynamic rankings with increasing number of teams

Tags: r, dynamic, indexing, rank

Small rep of my data:

```
Date <- as.Date(rep(c("2015-05-14", "2015-05-15","2015-05-16"),c(4,2,1)))
TEAM1 <- c("GSW","SAS","MIL","ATL","GSW","SAC","LAL")
TEAM2 <- c("HOU","MIN","NOP","LAL","SAS","TOR","GSW")
PCW_TEAM1 <- c(0.88,0.72,0.34,0.46,0.87,0.28,0.24)
PCW_TEAM2 <- c(0.67,0.31,0.52,0.23,0.74,0.48,0.90)
df <- data.frame(cbind(Date,TEAM1,TEAM2,PCW_TEAM1,PCW_TEAM2), stringsAsFactors=F)
df

    Date TEAM1 TEAM2 PCW_TEAM1 PCW_TEAM2
 1 16569   GSW   HOU      0.88      0.67
 2 16569   SAS   MIN      0.72      0.31
 3 16569   MIL   NOP      0.34      0.52
 4 16569   ATL   LAL      0.46      0.23
 5 16570   GSW   SAS      0.87      0.74
 6 16570   SAC   TOR      0.28      0.48
 7 16571   LAL   GSW      0.24       0.9
```

Imagine these are the first 7 games played of the NBA season. On the first date (16569) there are four games so the rank will be out of 8. However, once we add the next date (16570) there are two more matches and only two new teams since GSW and SAS already played on the first date.

I would like to rank the unique teams based on the winning percentage of the last available date. Output would look like this:

```
   Date TEAM1 TEAM2 PCW_TEAM1 PCW_TEAM2 RANK_TEAM1 RANK_TEAM2
1 16569   GSW   HOU      0.88      0.67          1          3
2 16569   SAS   MIN      0.72      0.31          2          7
3 16569   MIL   NOP      0.34      0.52          6          4
4 16569   ATL   LAL      0.46      0.23          5          8
5 16570   GSW   SAS      0.87      0.74          1          2
6 16570   SAC   TOR      0.28      0.48          9          5
7 16571   LAL   GSW      0.24       0.9         10          1
```

Notice that on the 5th row the Winning % of GSW is 0.87 and is ranked as 1. On the first row there is a Winning % that is higher (0.88) but is also GSW.

In this example there are 7 games and 10 unique teams. On the real data there are 30 unique teams.

```
unique(c(TEAM1,TEAM2))
[1] "GSW" "SAS" "MIL" "ATL" "SAC" "LAL" "HOU" "MIN" "NOP" "TOR"
```

I thought of creating a vector that would gather the last available winning percetage for each unique team and then rank the teams based on that information but didn't know how to do it or if that is the best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be easier to work with this data in long format.  The general idea in the code below is to expand the data so there is an entry for each team on each date (filled with NA values when they didn't play).  Then, group the data by team, and carry the winning percentage forward to fill the NA values (using `na.locf` from `zoo`) in order to determine the rankings for each date.  Then, transform back to wide format.

```
## Rearrange the data into a long format
long <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1:2, function(i)
    setNames(df[,c("Date", grep(i, names(df), value=T))], c("Date", "TEAM", "PCW"))))
long$index <- rep(1:nrow(df))  # used to transform back to wide

## Expand to include an entry for each team at each date
dat <- merge(expand.grid(Date=unique(long$Date), TEAM=unique(long$TEAM)), long, all=T)

## Fill in the NA values for each team, carrying forward previous win%
library(zoo)  # na.locf
dat <- cbind(do.call(rbind, lapply(split(dat, dat$TEAM), function(x)
    transform(x, PCW=na.locf(PCW, na.rm=F)))))

## Then, group by date and order (I would leave it in this form)
library(dplyr)
dat %>% group_by(Date) %>%
  mutate(RANK=match(TEAM, TEAM[order(PCW, decreasing = T)])) -> res

## Put it back into wide format
out <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(res[,-which(names(res)=="index")], res$index), function(x)
    setNames(cbind(x[1,], x[2,-1]), c("Date", paste0(names(x)[-1], 1), paste0(names(x)[-1], 2)))))
#    Date TEAM1 PCW1 RANK1 TEAM2 PCW2 RANK2
# 1 16569   GSW 0.88     1   HOU 0.67     3
# 2 16569   SAS 0.72     2   MIN 0.31     7
# 3 16569   MIL 0.34     6   NOP 0.52     4
# 4 16569   ATL 0.46     5   LAL 0.23     8
# 5 16570   GSW 0.87     1   SAS 0.74     2
# 6 16570   SAC 0.28     9   TOR 0.48     5
# 7 16571   GSW  0.9     1   LAL 0.24    10
```

Note that I didn't take precaution to ensure that TEAM1 and TEAM2 stay in the proper order, so for example, in the last row, the teams got switched compared to your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

```
TEAMs <- c(TEAM1,TEAM2)
teamsall <- unique(TEAMs)
PCWs <- c(PCW_TEAM1,PCW_TEAM2)
Dates <- c(Date,Date)
u = order(sapply(1:length(teamsall),function(x) {u=match(TEAMs,teamsall)==x;PCWs[u][which.max(Dates[u])]}),decreasing=T)
df$RANK1 = match(TEAM1,teamsall[u])
df$RANK2 = match(TEAM2,teamsall[u])
df
```

I think this may be one of the ways.